# Как вызвать 2 раза break; внутри switch?

Tags: c++

Не могу красиво выйти из цикла используя break внутри switch, успевает сработать только один раз.
пробовал еще return; но он выкидывает в такую далину куда мне не надо.

```
for (;;){
          switch (a)
          {
            case 0: a++; break;
            case 1: a++; break;
            case 2: a++; break;
            case 3: a++; break;
            case 4: break; break; // печально но не работает :(
            default:
                break;
          }
        }
```

Comment: Сделайте проверку какого-нибудь флага в `for` или используйте `goto`.

Comment: Проверку не хочется вызывать она будет все время вызываться, goto не слышал о таком

Comment: Красиво - это не про с++. Тут разве что запихнуть это все в функцию и сделать return.

Comment: @VTT нет не надо мне такое говорить :)

Comment: @VTT а return это хороший признак написания кода или плохо?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1257760/1016033

Comment: это костыль, замещающий убогость дизайна языка (отсутствие именованных блоков и безусловных переходов между ними)

Comment: @VTT, зачем именованные блоки, если существует оператор безусловного перехода `goto`?

Comment: @acade goto игнорирует области видимости, позволяет пропускать инициализации и т.п. О никчемности goto уже много писали.

Comment: @VTT прям все так плохо, может уже исправили эти недостатки с VS2019

Comment: А это фундаментальные недостатки.

Comment: Или просто достоинства (правда, не всем можно разрешать их использовать)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (;;)
{
  switch (a)
  {
    case 0: a++; break;
    case 1: a++; break;
    case 2: a++; break;
    case 3: a++; break;
    case 4:      goto DONE;
  }
}

DONE: ; // точка с запятой нужна только если потом идёт фигурная скобка
```

Comment: В принципе это более менее нормально, думаю лучше чем return

Comment: @loli, для return надо тащить код в функцию, что неудобно если он использует какие-то переменные отсюда.

Comment: Раз разработчики создали значит надо пользоваться :)

Comment: Интересно кто посчитал неправильным такое использование и почему....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan тот кто не любит goto и считает это костылем, но на деле я тоже так считаю, если часто использовать это, то даже не заметишь как весь код будет с одними goto, в идеале лучше избавится от него максимально быстро.
Еще интересно узнать как он работает на ассемблерном уровне, узнать точно что goto добавляет в код после компилирования.

Comment: @loli, безусловный переход (jump).

Answer (score 3):

Лучше сразу указать условие выхода из цикла:

```
while (a != 4)
{
    switch (a)
    {
    case 0: a++; break;
    case 1: a++; break;
    case 2: a++; break;
    case 3: a++; break;     
    }
}
```

Или вообше без   switch :

```
for (;;)
{
    if (a == 4) break;  
    ++a;
}
```

Comment: Ваш вариант не подойдет, причина :)
Первый вариант вызывает проверку каждый раз не равно ли 4, после каждого условие case, что довольно существенно.
Второй вариант может принимать только одно уникальное условие.

Comment: Первый вариант  дает возможность не рассматривать тело    цикла, если условие выполняется, что довольно существенно. Второй вариант вполне может принимать не только одно условие...

Comment: Да но что если выход из цикла зависит от условия а не от самого цикла?